# Print MigraDoc document to specific printer

Tags: printing, migradoc

I've created a MigraDoc/PdfSharp document and now need to send it to a specific printer without any user interaction.

What do I need to use as a Renderer and how do I set the printer path/name to the MigraDocPrintDocument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MigraDocPrintDocument is the correct class.

```
// Creates a PrintDocument that simplyfies printing of MigraDoc documents
MigraDocPrintDocument printDocument = new MigraDocPrintDocument();

// Attach the current printer settings
printDocument.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
```

We use System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog() to let the user select the printer (this dialog fills the printerSettings structure).
Use

```
internal PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
```

for the default printer. Change this structure to print with different settings or on a different printer.

Please note that with PDFsharp 1.31, printing will work with the GDI+ build only (the WPF build will not print the document correctly).